# Unable to send the complete form value in JSP to the Spring controller

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc, jsp

When I query the table in DB for CLUB, I get one fo the column value as 'WESTERN & CENTRAL'. I am trying to get the club value from UI and
 pass it to controller.

When i alert the club in JSP I get the  club name in the below format including the space

Club on change-> WESTERN & CENTRAL             (084   )

In the controller it's passing as club===='WESTERN' only but I need to send it as 'WESTERN & CENTRAL'. Also, in the URL I can see as

http://localhost:9080/admin/rates/points?club=WESTERN%20&%20CENTRAL%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20(084%20%20%20)

```
$("[id='clubs']").on("change", function(e){
    var club= $("#clubs").val();
     alert("Club on change-> "+club);
    window.location.replace("${pageContext.request.contextPath}" + "/rates/points?club="+club);    
});



@RequestMapping(value = Admin.URI_POINTS_GET, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getPoints(  
        @RequestParam(required = false, value = "club") String club,
        @ModelAttribute("RatesList") Rates RatesList,
        BindingResult results, 
        HttpServletRequest req) throws AdminSystemException { }
        System.out.println("club===="+club);
```

Please assist as how could i possibly send the whole club name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Space` is automatically getting converted to `%20` but for `ampersand(&)` you need to replace it with `%26` like below.

```
var strURLpiece = "WESTERN & CENTRAL (084 )";
strURLpiece.replace("&", "%26");
strURLpiece.replace(" ", "%20");
```

then send it to Controller it should work.

Hope it helps...!!

Comment: On change function, I included the below but still not sending the right value, do I have to replace & by %20 or %26? I tried both but doesn't work.                                                                        var club= $("#clubs").val();                                                                  
club.replace("&", "%20");